# Issue with loading large number of files

Tags: matlab

I am using CUDA/C++ to solve nonlinear system of equations and I am writing my results to mat files. After that, I am loading the data into Matlab, display it using `quiver` and `imagesc`, and make video using `writeVideo(video,getframe(gcf));`. Here is the sketch how I do it:

```
for i=1:numberoffiles
    load(strcat(data1,num2str('i')));
    load(strcat(data2,num2str('i')));
    load(strcat(data3,num2str('i')));
    load(strcat(data4,num2str('i')));
    load(strcat(data5,num2str('i')));
    subplot(...);
    quiver(...);
    imagesc(...);
    drawnow
    writeVideo(video,getframe(gcf));
end
```

When my `numberoffiles` was `100` it worked ok, although this process was getting slower and slower. Now my `numberoffiles=1000`, and after `i>400` it becomes really slow. I think, I forgot to clear something. But the thing is, that all my `.mat` files contain 1 array called `iu1`, therefore each load overwrites the array `iu1`. Anyone knows how to fix it? I feel like the problem is in RAM, since everything starts to work very slow on my PC during this process.

---

Here is my full code:

```
 function []=MakeVideo(framerate,name)
      video=VideoWriter(name);
      video.FrameRate=framerate;
      open(video);
      f=figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
      [names, values]=textread('config.txt','%s%f');
      stride=values(17);
      dt=values(16);
      resize=values(19)/32;
      max=values(15)/dt;
      dx=values(18)/values(19);
      for i=0:stride:max
          uitable(f,'Data',values,'ColumnWidth',{100},'ColumnName',          {'Values'},'RowName',names,'Position',[1150 500 350 800]);
          load(strcat('nx',num2str(i)));
          nxcu=iu1';
          clear('iu1');
          load(strcat('ny',num2str(i)));
          nycu=iu1';
          clear('iu1');
          ncu=nxcu+1i.*nycu;
          load(strcat('Psi',num2str(i)));
          Psicu=iu1';
          clear('iu1');
          load(strcat('phi',num2str(i)));
          phicu=iu1';
          clear('iu1');
          load(strcat('c',num2str(i)));
          ccu=iu1';
          clear('iu1');
          subplot(2,2,1)
          ncu=imresize(ncu,1/resize);
          npplot=angle(ncu)/2;
              imagesc(abs(ncu));
              colorbar
              hold on
              q=quiver(cos(npplot),sin(npplot));
              set(q,'color','black');
              set(q,'LineWidth',2);
              set(q,'ShowArrowHead','off');
              daspect([1 1 1])
              title('n')
              subplot(2,2,2)
              imagesc(phicu)
              daspect([1 1 1])
              colorbar
              title(strcat('w, wmin=',num2str(min(min(phicu)))))
              subplot(2,2,3) 
              Psix=imresize(Deriv(Psicu,'y',dx),1/resize);
              Psiy=imresize(-Deriv(Psicu,'x',dx),1/resize);
             q=quiver(Psix,Psiy);
              set(q,'color','black');
              set(q,'LineWidth',2);
              daspect([1 1 1])
              title('Psi')
              subplot(2,2,4)
              imagesc(ccu)
              daspect([1 1 1])
              colorbar
                        title(strcat('time=',num2str(dt*i),'mic=',num2str(min(min(ccu)))))
              drawnow
              writeVideo(video,getframe(gcf));
      end
      close gcf
      close(video)
  end
```

In the working folder I have the following list of files:

```
nx0.mat, ny0.mat, c0.mat, Psi0.mat, phi0.mat,
nx1000.mat, ny1000.mat, c1000.mat, Psi1000.mat, phi1000.mat,
nx2000.mat, ny2000.mat, c2000.mat, Psi2000.mat, phi2000.mat,
.............................................
nx500000.mat, ny500000.mat, c500000.mat, Psi500000.mat, phi500000.mat
```

Each mat file has variable `iu1`. This variable is matrix 512x512.

Comment: A 512x512 array requires about 2MB of RAM...using 1000 of them would be 2GB.  Even if your computer has a lot of RAM, I've seen MATLAB run slow when it gets loaded with more than 1GB of data.  Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: One thing to check would be to insert a call to `whos()` everytime you load a file...that would show you what variables are in the workspace (and how much space they take up), and you could see if you were clearing memory the way you need to.

Comment: I thought that each time I load the file, I update my variable iu1. That means, the amount of RAM doesn't increase

Comment: Just a thought: are you using linux? I have had an issue in the past when loading a large number of files through MATLAB on linux. The issue appeared to be that the files were all being cached preferentially over anything else in RAM, causing basically every other program to be forced into swap. I was able to fix this with a bit of a bodge-job workaround by disabling the swap temporarily.

Comment: @ MrAzzaman, I use windows7

Comment: MATLAB can be very bad about closing file-handles, so you may be running into problems with an excessive number of open files.  You could try calling  `fclose('all')` periodically (every 100 files?) to see if that helps.

Comment: Also, you can verify whether RAM is the problem by opening the task manager in Windows, and watching the memory usage while you run your MATLAB program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! It is not the RAM problem, only 25% of the RAM is used. Using fclose('all') helps to accelerate the process. You can post the answer